# Anticommutation and Bogoliubove transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, commutator, ising-model, anticommutator

I am given the following transformation:
\begin{equation}                                                         
            \begin{bmatrix}                                                      
                a(q) \\                                                          
                a^\dagger(-q)                                                    
            \end{bmatrix}                                                        
            =                                                                    
            \begin{bmatrix}                                                      
                cos\theta(q) & i\sin\theta(q) \\                                 
                i\sin\theta(q) & cos\theta(q)                                    
            \end{bmatrix}                                                        
            \begin{bmatrix}                                                      
                \alpha(q) \\                                                     
                \alpha^\dagger(-q)                                               
            \end{bmatrix}                                                        
        \end{equation}
And
\begin{align}
\left\{ a(q), a(q')\right\} &= 0\\
\left\{ a^\dagger(q), a^\dagger(q')\right\} &= 0\\
\left\{ a(q), a^\dagger(q')\right\} &= \delta_{q,q'}
\end{align}

I need to prove the anticommutation $\left\{ \alpha(q), \alpha(q')\right\} = 0$, but I am stuck and haven't been able to figure it out.

**My Work**
\begin{equation}                                                         
            \begin{bmatrix}                                                      
                \alpha(q) \\                                                     
                \alpha^\dagger(-q)                                               
            \end{bmatrix}                                                        
            =                                                                    
            \begin{bmatrix}                                                      
                cos\theta(q) & -i\sin\theta(q) \\                                
                -i\sin\theta(q) & cos\theta(q)                                   
            \end{bmatrix}                                                        
            \begin{bmatrix}                                                      
                a(q) \\                                                          
                a^\dagger(-q)                                                    
            \end{bmatrix}                                                        
        \end{equation}
Then
\begin{align*}                                                   
                    \left\{\alpha(k), \alpha(k') \right\} &= \left\{             
                        \cos\theta(k)a(k) - i\sin(k)a^\dagger(-k),               
                        \cos\theta(k')a(k') - i\sin\theta(k')a^\dagger(-k')        
                        \right\} \\                                              
                    \left\{\alpha(k), \alpha(k') \right\} &=                     
                    \left\{\cos\theta(k)a(k),-i\sin\theta(k')a^\dagger(-k')        
                    \right\}  +                                                  
                    \left\{-i\sin\theta(k)a^\dagger(-k),\cos\theta(k')a(k')        
                    \right\} \\                                                  
                    \left\{\alpha(k), \alpha(k') \right\} &=                     
                    -i\cos\theta(k)\sin\theta(k')\delta_{k,-k'}                  
                    -i\sin\theta(k)\cos\theta(k')\delta_{k',-k}                  
                \end{align*}
Which is not equal to 0, unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

$\delta_{k,-k'}$ ensures that RHS can be non-vanishing only when $k=-k'$. Now, when $k=-k'$, then to cancel the anti-commutator we need $\theta(k) = - \theta(-k)$.

I think that the anti-commutation relations won't hold in general. We use them to impose additional constraints on the transformation parameters (constraints of form $\theta(k) = - \theta(-k)$ for any $k$). Note, that this is nothing new; the anti-commutation relations are the reason for the specific choice of the transformation matrix (with trigonometric functions).

There is also a simpler reason for $\theta(k) = - \theta(-k)$. Take:
\begin{equation}
a(q) = \cos(\theta(q)) \alpha(q) + i \sin(\theta(q)) \alpha^\dagger(-q),
\end{equation}
apply hermitian conjugation and take $q=-k$. You get:
\begin{equation}
a^\dagger(-k) = \cos(\theta(-k)) \alpha^\dagger(-k) - i \sin(\theta(-k)) \alpha(k).
\end{equation}
Compare with the definition:
\begin{equation}
a^\dagger(-k) = \cos(\theta(k)) \alpha^\dagger(-k) + i \sin(\theta(k)) \alpha(k)
\end{equation}
to see that it can only be true if $\theta(k) = -\theta(-k)$.

Comment: But is $\theta_k = k$?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I answered too hasty. I edited my answer